# Не работает русский язык в debian

Tags: debian, locale

Не работает русский язык в tmux, в screen работает русский язык на половину. Уже всё пробывал делать, стоит Debian 11, хостинг appletec.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После установки всех нужны пакетов зайдите в `.bashrc` и добавьте это строчку - `export LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8`
Должно это выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]